# C# and Microsoft Excel 9.0 Object Library (Excel 2000) getting a cell coordinate excel style

Tags: c#, excel, range, coordinates, cell

Is there a way with Excel 9.0 Object Library to get a cell coordinate (from a range or cell) "Excel style" for example: A1 or C4 instead of [1,1] and [4,3]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Address`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb213510.aspx) property.

```
string addr = range.get_Address(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
    Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```